# Group Expressions in Reportviewer

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I am trying to figure out how to group data contained inside a Table.  I want to be able to group by data that is similar in a column.

For example:

1. Bob,   23,  Cereal
2. Bob,   24,  Oatmeal
3. Susan, 25,  Cream
4. Susan, 26,  Horse

The above, I am trying to find an expression to use that will allow me to group both Bobs together, and both Susans together.

I am assuming this is a simple thing to do, however, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please could you edit the question to show what the output would be given the example input data you have provided?

Comment: Output will be two groups in the same table.  I am just trying to determine the "Group Expression" that would actually create such a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up a sort order.

Edit your group and go to the Sorting tab.  Then I'd put in `=Fields!Name.Value` with Ascending as the Direction. Forgive me if I'm not understanding the question correctly.

If you have a static number of names you could statically assign your groups with `=Fields!Name.Value="Bob"` and another group with `=Fields!Name.Value="Susan"`